# Mini TV for android not recognized as a device

Tags: android

I recently bought a mini TV for android (API level 17) and was wondering if it was possible for the device to be recognized by adb as a testing device when I write adb devices command in sdk/platform-tools in Windows. 
I searched for this everywhere and managed to make my personal phone be recognized by the PC but the mini TV for android seems to work differently. Also, there is not much information concerning this problem.
Any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: did you find "enable usb debugging" in the settings , if there are any on the mini TV ?

Comment: Yes...it was a default setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem regarding the adb drivers for the mini tv. I had Rockchip MK 808 series.

I installed [moborobo](http://www.moborobo.com/.) and re connected the mini tv and then the driver was installed. Also make sure your google USB driver are up to date in SDK.

I referred to the following links for solution

http://freaktab.com/forum/tv-player-support/rk3188-devices/beelink-tronsmart-t428-mk908-etc/5369-adb-connection

http://freaktab.com/forum/tv-player-support/rk3066-devices/mk-models-mk808-802-etc/5036-mk808-adb-android-debug-bridge